# Look for Array key with value if equals php

Tags: php, arrays, variables, if-statement, equals

I would like to use mt_random to generate a number, this is what the code does, then i would like to see if it equals a value in the array to print out the text version.

**Example:** if result is 2 and key [2] is 2, print "two"

`$nul` in this example is the ultimate output.

Finaly registered on this forum! would like to thank everyone for helping people out all these years. my first question so please do not  bash me lol!

I would like to use mt_random to generate a number, this is what the code does, then i would like to see if it equals a value in the array to print out the text version.

```
  <?php 

    $min = 1;
    $max = 6;
    $array = [
        "1" => "one",     
            "2" => "two",
        "3" => "three",
        "4" => "four",
        "5" => "five",
            "6" => "six",
    ];

    if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {    

    $nul = "Druk op gooi";

    }


    if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {      
        $random = mt_rand($min,$max);         
        $nul = $random;
    }


    ?>
    <form action="dobbelen3.php" method="post">


      <div class="dobbel" id="dobbelid">
      <?php

      if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {  
        echo  "<img src='images/$nul.JPG' width='121' height='115' />";
      }
      ?>
       </div>

    <input type="text" name="Project" value="

    <?php 

    echo $nul; 

    ?>

    "  style="width:121px;"/>

     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
          </form>
```

Comment: I'm not putting this an an answer because it does not directly address your question, but you might try [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) or access `$array[$random]` This does rely on PHP loose typing, since you are using sting/numbers for your array indices.

Comment: Tnx! now i learned that one too, very usefull! can shorten the code :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the key of the array, so you can just fetch it's value...

```
$random = 2;
$string = $array[$random];
```

You could even make your code more concise:

```
$array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
$string = $array[$random-1];
```

An array starts with 0 by default so `$array[0]` would contain "one", that's why you need to subtract one from the actual value you want.

```
$myArr = array('foo', 'bar');
// would be identical to
$myArr = array(0 => 'foo', 1 => 'bar');
```

this is called *zero based index*

Comment: Tnx that fixed it! cant vote you up yet cuzz im new, i think i can vote it up later i guess.

Great learned stuff in 5 tnx to both of you!.

Comment: You guys were so fast i wasnt able, it said cant select answer in 4 minutes lol, selected now, what does the -1 actually do behind $random?

Comment: aah ok, didn't know that :) I've updated the answer with a small explanation about the `-1`